# Background color for different terms in equation

Tags: equations, color, subequations

How to put a different background color for different terms in one single equation. Below is the example I tried. I need boxed term in the equation to have a background of green, the second term with magenta, and the last term to be a yellow background. how to achieve this.  The expected result looks like the last equation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgreen}{HTML}{90EE90}
\newcommand{\boxedeq}[2]{\begin{empheq}[box={\fboxsep=6pt\fbox}]{align}\label{#1}#2\end{empheq}}
\newcommand{\coloredeq}[2]{\begin{empheq}[box=\colorbox{lightgreen}]{align}\label{#1}#2\end{empheq}}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
 \begin{align}
 \mathcal{\bar{L}}&=\boxed{\textcolor{red}{\frac{\beta^4}{2}\left(\int_{0}^{1}\,\hspace{-0.05in} \left( \psi(\eta)\right)^2 \diff\eta + \sum_{j=1}^{n} \gamma_{j}^3\, \int_{0}^{\gamma_{j}}  \hspace{-0.05in} \left( \chi_{j}(\xi)\right)^2 \diff\xi \right)}}-\nonumber \\ &\quad  \textcolor{blue}{\frac{1}{2}\,\left(\int_{0}^{1} \hspace{-0.05in} \left(\frac{\partial^2\psi(\eta)}{\partial \eta^2}\right)^2 \diff\eta  +\sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_{j}\, \int_{0}^{\gamma_{j}}\left(\frac{\partial \chi_{j}(\xi)}{\partial \xi}\right)^2 \diff\xi \right)}+\nonumber \\ &\quad \sum_{j=1}^{n}\lambda_{j}^{*}\left(\psi(\zeta_{j})-\chi_{j}(\gamma)\right) \nonumber  
 \end{align}
 \end{subequations}
\coloredeq{eq:second}{c_i = \langle\psi|\phi\rangle} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The operative part is given below -- please see if it meets the rquirement

```
          \tikz[baseline]{\node[fill=green!25, rectangle, anchor=base]
                {.............}%<-------------------------------item to be colored 
                }
```

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
 \begin{align}
 \mathcal{\bar{L}}&=\boxed{\textcolor{red}{\frac{\beta^4}{2}\left(\int_{0}^{1}\,\hspace{-0.05in} \left( \psi(\eta)\right)^2 \diff\eta + \sum_{j=1}^{n} \gamma_{j}^3\, \int_{0}^{\gamma_{j}}  \hspace{-0.05in} \left( \chi_{j}(\xi)\right)^2 \diff\xi \right)}}-\nonumber \\ &\quad  \textcolor{blue}{\frac{1}{2}\,\left(\int_{0}^{1} \hspace{-0.05in} \left(\frac{\partial^2\psi(\eta)}{\partial \eta^2}\right)^2 \diff\eta  +\sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_{j}\, \int_{0}^{\gamma_{j}}\left(\frac{\partial \chi_{j}(\xi)}{\partial \xi}\right)^2 \diff\xi \right)}+\nonumber \\ &\quad \sum_{j=1}^{n}\lambda_{j}^{*}\left(\psi(\zeta_{j})-\chi_{j}(\gamma)\right) \nonumber  
 \end{align}
 \end{subequations}
{eq:second} \tikz[baseline]{
                \node[fill=green!25, rectangle, anchor=base]
                {$c_i = \langle\psi|\phi\rangle$} 
                            }
\end{document}
```

**Answer2**

The other option is to use `\colorbox`, provided by the package `xcolor`. Here's the result (along with some streamlining of your code and replacing `\left` and `\right` directives with explicit sizing instructions):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,amsmath,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}
%\begin{subequations}
\begin{align*}
\colorbox{green}{$\mathcal{\bar{L}}$}
   &=\boxed{%
   \textcolor{red}{ \frac{\beta^4}{2} \biggl(\,
   \colorbox{green}{$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} 
   ( \psi(\eta))^2 \diff\eta$} 
   + \sum_{j=1}^{n} \gamma_{j}^3 \int_{0}^{\gamma_{j}}  
   ( \chi_{j}(\xi) )^2 \diff\xi 
   \biggr) } % end \textcolor
   }  % end \boxed
   \\ 
   &\quad - 
   \textcolor{blue}{ \frac{1}{2} \biggl( 
   \int_{0}^{1} \biggl(
   \frac{\partial^2\psi(\eta)}{\partial \eta^2}\biggr)^{\!2} \diff\eta  
   +\sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_{j} \! \int_{0}^{\gamma_{j}}
   \biggl(\frac{\partial \chi_{j}(\xi)}{\partial \xi}\biggr)^{\!2} 
   \diff\xi \biggr)}\\ 
   &\quad +
   \sum_{j=1}^{n}\lambda_{j}^{*} \bigl(\psi(\zeta_{j})-\chi_{j}(\gamma)\bigr)  
\end{align*}
%\end{subequations}
{eq:second} \tikz[baseline]{
                \node[fill=green!25, rectangle, anchor=base]
                {$c_i = \langle\psi|\phi\rangle$} 
                            }
\end{document}
```

Comment: not working showing some package error, Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon? ... {$c_i = \langle\psi|\phi\rangle$} }

Comment: edited the answer --please have a look

Comment: +1. I've taken the liberty of streamlining the code in "Answer 2"; feel free to revert.